# Select documents randomly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to know if there is a way to select randomly documents in CosmosDB (Microsoft Azure).

Here is my code, I do not know what to add before "Take(20)":

```
public List<LeafBook> BooksList { get; private set; }

public async Task<List<LeafBook>> GetBookAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // The query excludes completed TodoItems

        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<LeafBook>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })

             .Take(20)            
             .AsDocumentQuery();

        BooksList = new List<LeafBook>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            BooksList.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<LeafBook>());
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", e.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return BooksList;
}
```

Comment: There is no native method for extracting random samples (unless you use the MongoDB API with aggregation pipeline). Maybe consider randomizing on a known set of values within your data domain? Date ranges?

Comment: I do not have a approach if you have an Idea I will take

Comment: Every document has a field : "NumberoftheBook" which is the number of storage of the document (like unique ID for an SQL database)

Answer (score 1):

kikis, as @David Makogon said in the comment, you could follow the [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/) which is linked by the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20100751-allow-for-random-sample) to get random result in cosmos db mongo api.

However ,there is no such native feature in cosmos db sql api. So , maybe you need to adopt workaround.

You could use `stored procedure` to implement such feature in cosmos db,please refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/@murdockcrc/documentdb-retrieving-a-random-document-7ef4a27e8591).

In this workaround, the most important thing is that it could potentially iterate through your whole collection, depending on the value of filterString you pass to the sproc upon execution. You should make sure `filterString` is as lightweight on the database as possible.

Or you could just get 20 random `NumberoftheBook` properties before the query, and take that for query filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this to get one document : var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<LeafBook>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
                     .Where(b=> b.NumberOfTheBook==10)                                       
                      .AsDocumentQuery();        but I have this error : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: @kikis You mean you met the error when you use linq to filter documents?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

1. Get the total no of documents in the collection using
   `dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT c.id FROM c")`
2. Use `Random` to select random `int`s between 0 and the total (minus 1) obtained from above.
3. Fetch the documents corresponding to the `id`s obtained (in step 1) at the indexes (in step 2)

I haven't tried this out but let me know!

Comment: thanks but I do not know how to adapt : dc.CreateDocumentQuery(update.SelfLink, "SELECT c.id FROM c")   with :  var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<LeafBook>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })

             .Take(20)            
             .AsDocumentQuery();